# Groovy clouse test with Spock

Tags: testing, groovy

How we can test groovy closuer with spock i.e. httpbuilder

```
def visitGoogle(String urlRequest, Map query){
    def output
    http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.TEXT) { req ->
         uri.path = urlRequest
        if(query)
            uri.query = query

        headers.Accept = 'text/*'

        response.success = { resp, reader ->
           def bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bytes << reader
           output = bytes.toString("UTF-8")
        }

        response.'404' = { resp ->
           output = "Not found"
        }
    }

    return output 
}
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to test?

Comment: 100% coverage of my code. I want to test success and 404 both.